# How to re-direct blog article URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, symphony-cms

I am trying to redirect a bunch of old blog article URLs using the `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch ^/index\.php/global/article/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/article/$1
```

This doesn't really work, however, because my CMS  seems to get confused by the `index.php` bit and keeps adding `?symphony-page=` to all the URLs.

It's probably this part that is responsible:

```
### FRONTEND REWRITE - Will ignore files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*\/?)$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following (comments included to explain):

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# First, redirect the old URIs to the new ones via a 301 redirect.
# This will allow the CMS to take over using the rules that follow.
RewriteRule ^index.php/global/article/(.+)$ /blog/article/$1 [L,R=301]

# Frontend Rewrites - for the CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*\/?)$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks a lot. I suppose that @Mi-Creativity's solution works equally well but I haven't tested it yet. I upvoted all your answers and comments, though :-)

Comment: Phew, and I thought a voting troll was lurking around. ;) Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#-- Input URL >>  http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/global/article/abc


### FRONTEND REWRITE - Will ignore files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*\/?)$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/global/article/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ blog/article/%1  [R=301, L]


#--Output URL >>  http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/article/abc
```

---

I've tested the above with this [**htaccess.madewithlove**](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it seems like it will work just fine, hopefully it will work for you too

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. You are using an internal redirect here, not a 301. The OP specifically wants to *redirect* old URIs to the new ones so that the CMS can take over.

Comment: @MikeRockett, if I understood correctly it is just the the last `RewriteRule ^.*$ blog/article/%1 [L]` needs to have an `[L, R=301]` for  permanent redirect, if this is not the case I'd gladly remove the answer if it is wrong

Comment: That would make your answer slightly more correct. However, the rule needs to move to the top and the CMS rewrite requires the `L` flag.

Comment: I've updated the answer to have the `R=301` flag but when I move it above to the top that http://htaccess.madewithlove.be shows the below `RewriteCond`s were not met, same thing for your code http://i.stack.imgur.com/JinWl.png ! maybe that website is not reliable

Comment: Yes, the tester is more of an emulator, and doesn't catch everything. In this case, it catches the redirect, but does not continue the next iteration. I do not use the emulator. When not sure about something, I have a local virtual host that is used for testing. That way, I can see exactly what is going on.